# Need help using different 'page-templates' for one-page wordpress site sections

Tags: php, wordpress

This is my second question, and I promise as soon as I feel like I can help others, I'm gonna return the favours to the community!

I'm building a one page Wordpress site with different sections, working from _S theme and learning as I go.

I already have all my different pages being pulled into the front-page, but I would like the different sections to have different layouts and elements. To be specific - in one section I would like content to be pulled in along side an iFrame that float next to each other. To do this I know that I need to call a custom page template that specifies two floating div containers (I'm building using Bootstrap).

In the front-page.php, I've written this:

```
<?php
if ( get_option( 'show_on_front' ) == 'posts' ) {
    get_template_part( 'index' );
} elseif ( 'page' == get_option( 'show_on_front' ) ) { ?>


<?php get_header(); ?>



<section class="home">
    <div class="entry-content">
    <?php 

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'order' => 'ASC'
        );
    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);

    ?>

    <?php

    while($the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

    <?php if (is_page(9)) : ?>

    <?php get_template_part('play','page');?>

<?php else : ?>


    <?php get_template_part('content', 'page');?>


<?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>




</div>
</section>





<?php 
get_footer();
}
?>
```

Which works perfectly in bringing in my different page sections, but I can't see how to call a different for the page (called 'play' or with the ID of 9).

I have already created a template called play-page

Any ideas?

Thanks masses

Harry

Comment: What if you display some dummy text right after `<?php if (is_page(9)) : ?> askdjfkjsdkfjksdjflasd` and see if the text shows up.

Comment: Nothing shows up - I think my problem may be that I'm not selecting the right section due to me bringing in the content from page-9 to the front-page rather than working with page-9 itself.

If I call it in a different way I am able to get the different page template, but then it uses that template for all of the different pages being brought in

I'm sorry this is so confusing, I'm still learning all the terminology

Comment: OK, can you add this before the loop <?php echo '<pre>'; 
 print_r($the_query); 
echo '</pre>'; ?> and see if you get all the pages in the query.

Comment: Yes I get all the pages in the query. I think I may have explained badly / be missing something very very basic. 

In a very very simple example of what I need, it's that I want to style some sections on my front-page differently from one another. e.g. I want blog posts to come under 'news' and the container to have a max-height of 600px. Without writing divs in the Wordpress editor, is there something incredibly basic I'm missing about how to do this?

Comment: Make different templates for each part, then call get_template_part() multiple times on the page, once for each template.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you want to display 3 sections (about, work, contact) on the custom front page, you can create per page template for each section, like:

```
section-about.php
section-work.php
section-contact.php
```

In `page-about.php` like this:

```
<div class="section-about">
  <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
```

And use `section-work`, `section-contact` for other 2 pages.

Then you create 3 pages in the Dashboard and assign each to its template.

Now, you can add the loop in your `font-page.php`

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post__in' => array(1, 2, 3) // the ids of those pages
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
?>

<?php while($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

    <?php
        the_title();
        the_content();
        // etc
    ?>

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help! I'll get there slowly, really appreciate it.